# Spilliting Polygon into Square

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **array of abstract shapes coordinates**. I want to **split that shape into** a number of **squares** and get their coordinates like shown in the image shown below:
[image]

**For that i have tried is:**

Find the extreme left and top coordinates and further with the loop find the relative position of the square coordinates. But this includes the square on outer side of it.

**My Code:**

```
 var intersections = [];
var y = -9999;
        var x = -9999;
        var ym = 9999;
        var xm = 9999;

        var boundry = [];
        //loop to find the extreme cordinates

        for(var k=0; k <points.length; k++){

            var pt = [];

            pt.push(points[k].x);
            pt.push(points[k].y);
            boundry.push(pt);

            if(points[k].x > x){
                x = points[k].x;
            }

            if(points[k].y > y){
                y = points[k].y;
            }

            if(points[k].x < xm){
                xm = points[k].x;
            }

            if(points[k].y < ym){
                ym = points[k].y;
            }
        }

for(var o = ym; o < y; o = o + split_diff){
            console.log('o',o);
            for(var i = xm; i < x; i = i + split_diff){

                //divided points!
                var isInside = checkIn(o,x);
                if(isInside){
                   intersections.push(o,x);
                 }
            }


        }
```

**What i want**

Is there any other way to achieve same without getting the outer squares. like any external library or so.  Thank you for the help in advance.

```
function split_polygon(points){
 // above code here
}
//array of all the intersection cordinates
```

Comment: The image does not show only squares, but also other figures near the border of the polygon. It is not clear what the output is you need. Things would be a *lot* clearer if you would provide sample input (in JS format) and the corresponding output (also in JS format) that you expect to get from that input. That way there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @trincot `points` is an array of the 3d space coordinate, shown in image with the green dots. I am trying to get the coordinates of all the intersections of the lines.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. Things would be a lot clearer if you would provide sample input (in JS format) and the corresponding output (also in JS format) that you expect to get from that input. That way there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Also, you speak of 3d space coordinates, which makes it even more confusing. The image is 2d, and also your code seems to work with 2d.

Comment: @trincot oh got it, i will update the question.

Comment: @trincot Even though the coordinates in 3d space, i need to work all this in 2d. The image perfectly explains that from the shape vertices which i pass to the function which will return me all the intersections of every line in the polygon space and around it's boundry

Comment: The update does not include a sample input (in JS format) and the corresponding output (also in JS format) that you expect to get from that input. That way there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @trincot like from passing the array `points= [ [0,0],[1,2],[2,1],[2,0] ]` i expect output to be 'intersections = [ [0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,0] ]` i hope this will help

Comment: What defines the distance between the "intersection" points (the square size). Should the coordinates be values that are a multiple of that size, or what defines the starting point?

Comment: @trincot the starting point is extreme left and bottom coordinate as shown above ym and xm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cope with all kinds of polygons (even non-convex), you could scan across a horizontal line where that line crosses the polygon and so determine which are the line segment(s) of that line that are interior to the polygon.

Once you have that it is rather easy to pick the points on those line segments.

Repeat for several horizontal lines (at the required vertical distance).

Here is a snippet that allows you to click on a canvas to define a polygon. To create the final closing edge of the polygon, click the button. At that time the algorithm to create that dot-grid will also kick in.

```js
function intersectionY(edge, y) {
    const [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]] = edge;
    const dir = Math.sign(y2 - y1);
    if (dir && (y1 - y)*(y2 - y) <= 0) return { x: x1 + (y-y1)/(y2-y1) * (x2-x1), dir };
}

function tilePolygon(points, tileSize){
    const minY = Math.min(...points.map(p => p[1]));
    const maxY = Math.max(...points.map(p => p[1]));
    const minX = Math.min(...points.map(p => p[0]));
    const gridPoints = [];
    for (let y = minY; y <= maxY; y += tileSize) {
        // Collect x-coordinates where polygon crosses this horizontal line (y)
        const cuts = [];
        let prev = null;
        for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            const cut = intersectionY([points[i], points[(i+1)%points.length]], y);
            if (!cut) continue;
            if (!prev || prev.dir !== cut.dir) cuts.push(cut);
            prev = cut;
        }
        if (prev && prev.dir === cuts[0].dir) cuts.pop(); 
        // Now go through those cuts from left to right toggling whether we are in/out the polygon
        let dirSum = 0;
        let startX = null;
        for (let cut of cuts.sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x)) {
            dirSum += cut.dir;
            if (dirSum % 2) { // Entering polygon
                if (startX === null) startX = cut.x;
            } else if (startX !== null) { // Exiting polygon
                // Genereate grid points on this horizontal line segement
                for (let x = minX + Math.ceil((startX - minX) / tileSize)*tileSize; x <= cut.x; x += tileSize) {
                    gridPoints.push([x, y]);
                }
                startX = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return gridPoints;
}

function controller() { // I/O for this interactive snippet
    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const points = [];

    function drawLines(points, close, color = "black") {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(...points[0]);
        for (let point of points) ctx.lineTo(...point);
        if (close) ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function drawPoint(x, y, color = "black") {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }

    document.querySelector("#polclose").addEventListener("click", function () {
        const gridPoints = tilePolygon(points, 10);
        // Output:
        drawLines(points, true);
        gridPoints.forEach(p => drawPoint(...p, "red"));
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        const x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
        const y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
        points.push([x, y]);
        drawLines(points, false);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        const x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
        const y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
        document.querySelector("#output").textContent = x + ", " + y;
    });
}
controller();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
Click at different coordinates to create a polygon:<br>
<canvas></canvas><br><button id="polclose">Complete Polygon</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I modified the outer for loop so i get it with the same y values sets.